# Set x and y coordinates of Listview item programmatically android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I use listview. But I want to set x and y position of listview item. Ex: I want like this below draw image. Is it possible? If yes give me any idea or if no then give me another suggestions.

```
 ---------------------
|                     | 
|  |start point       |   
|                     |
|---------------------|
|                     |
|      |start point   | 
|                     |  
----------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create a custom ArrayAdapter
- Override the getView of a ArrayAdapter
- Create in the getView your row layout or use a your row layout from a xml layout resource
- For the row layout, you can't (easy) use x and y. You can use android:layout_margin or     something like that for positioning

for more info, here is a tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Within your customer adapter, on the getView method,   set the X margin or padding for your raw layout, depending on your condition.

Comment: But I have a x coordinate. Can I set directly x coordinate in getView method to set item.

Comment: to insure that you will support all device, its better to make your start x relative to 0. after that just set marginLeft to your x start point. if you can provide more code it will be sample to give you a more clear answer.